# How to prove the following limit inferior property?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $\{f_n(x)\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of continuous functions on an interval $I$ (bounded or not) such that $\{f_n(x)\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ is lower bounded for any $x \in I$ and let $g_n(x)=\inf\,\{f_{n+1}(x),f_{n+2}(x),f_{n+3}(x),\dots\}$ for any $x\in I$, $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

If $\lim_{n \to \infty} g_n(x)=g(x)$ is finite for all $x \in I$ and if $g(x)$ is a continuous function on $I$, then $g_n(x)$ is a continuous function on $I$ for any $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

Answer (score 0):

It's not true.

Let $f_n : [0,1] \to [0,1]$ be a continuous function with $f_n(0)=1$, $f_n = 0$ on $[1/(n+1), 1/n]$ and $f_n = 1$ on $[1/(n-1), 1]$.  (You may wish to draw a picture.)  Then for any $n$, we have $g_n(0) = 1$ and $g_n = 0$ on $(0, 1/n]$, so $g_n$ is not continuous.  Yet $g_n = 1$ on $[1/(n-1), 1]$, since all $f_n, f_{n+1}, \dots$ are identically 1 on that interval, and hence $\lim_{n \to \infty} g_n(x) = 1$ for all $x$, so that the limiting function $g(x)=1$ exists and is continuous.